# PHP Ajax Sending Array

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I'm sending an array to a PHP file named *update.php* and in all previous versions of this script it's worked, but for some bizarre reason it isn't working in this instance.

Here are the files:

```
var phpLocation = '/admin/_backend' + $( this ).attr("action"),
    usergroup = $('input:hidden[name="usergroup"]').val(),
    serializedData = $('input:checkbox[name="permission"]:checked').map(function () {
                         return this.value;
                      }).get();

var ajaxData = {'usergroup_permissions': serializedData, 'usergroup' : usergroup};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: phpLocation,
    data: ajaxData,
    success: function(data){
        $("#post_reply").html(data);

        console.log( ajaxData );
    }
});
```

When attempting to grab and turn `usergroup_permissions` from an array into a list separated by commas, it doesn't seem to work.

Even when using `$_POST['usergroup_permissons']` it doesn't seem to work..

```
$permission_list = implode(",", $_POST['usergroup_permissions']);
```

**Edit**
This is the console.log output
[image]

`print_r( $_POST );` returns:

[image]

Comment: What is the .get() at the end of serializedData? Could we see the result of a console.log(serializedData) please? Also, is that script running after the DOM has been drawn?

Comment: @Salketer The honest truth is I'm not too sure but it works in getting the array. I'll edit the original post to include an image of the `console.log( ajaxData );`

Comment: ok, can we see the content of $_POST? Can you check in the network tab that it actually got sent?

Comment: A print_r() or var_dump() of $_POST will quickly tell you what the problem is.

Comment: does it suppose serializedData to be a string ?? because you call it "serializedData"

Comment: @Spudley Thanks for that, it did help but I'm still unsure where to go. I have attached the result of that.

Comment: @MohammadAlabed I don't think so because this method is working elsewhere in my javascript.

Comment: the array keys in the `print_r()` output do not match the ones in `ajaxData`. Specifically, `ajaxAdata` contains `usergroup_permissions`, whereas `print_r()` shows `permission`. I can't see why this would be happening from the code you've provided, but I suspect it's a good pointer toward the cause.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Your `ajaxData contains `usergroup_permissions` and `usergroup` but your `print_r` shows `permission` not `usergroup_permissions`.  Are you sure you are posting to the right script? Or..random guess about your backend setup but I assume maybe you have a route/view and you aren't referencing the right param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out that somewhere else in the script I am calling a serialize of the whole form and so the `permission` in the second image is coming from that (because it's the name of the checkbox).

I've now rectified this and it is working fine.

Thank you very much for all of your help.